# Python function call with optional Data class parameter causes error

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing, python-dataclasses

I am trying to pass a data class object as a optional parameter to a function, but got stuck.
So, here is a simplified code describing the problem.
First, I am defining a data class:

```
@dataclass
class SomeObject:
    A: str
```

If i make the parameter non-optional, there is no problem:

```
def printObject0 (Index, AnyObject):
    print(Index, AnyObject.A)

Object1 = SomeObject ("A")

printObject0 (1, Object1)

# gives:
# 1 A
```

However, if i try to make it an optional parameter *args like this...

```
def printObject1 (Index, *AnyObject):
    print(Index, AnyObject.A)

Object1 = SomeObject ("A")

printObject1 (1, Object1)
# gives:
# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'A'
```

...or with **kwargs like this...

```
def printObject2 (Index, **AnyObject):
    print(Index, AnyObject.A)
    
Object1 = SomeObject ("A")

printObject2 (1, Object1)
# gives:
# TypeError: printObject2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

i get the above-stated errors.

Does anyone have an idea how i can make the object optional?

Comment: def printObject1 (Index, AnyObject=None):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function argument `*AnyObject` means the `AnyObject` is a tuple of all remaining positional arguments. So you can do

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class SomeObject:
    A: str

def printObject_1(idx, *objs):
    print(idx, objs[0].A)

printObject_1(1, SomeObject('A'))  # 1 A
```

Furthermore, the function argument `**AnyObject` means that `AnyObject` is a dictionary of all remaining keyword arguments. So you can do:

```py
def printObject_2(idx, **objs):
    print(idx, objs['foo'].A)

printObject_2(1, foo=SomeObject('A'))  # 1 A
```

BTW: Usually, optional function arguments have default values, like

```py
def printObject_3(idx, obj=SomeObject('A')):
    print(idx, obj.A)


printObject_3(1)  # 1 A
printObject_3(1, SomeObject('ABC'))  # 1 ABC
printObject_3(1, obj=SomeObject('ABC'))  # 1 ABC
```

Normally, the second function call should be avoided because it is more error-prone.

But since the default argument value is mutable in this case (see below) it is safer to do

```py
def printObject_4(idx, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        obj = SomeObject('A')
    print(idx, obj.A)

printObject_4(1)  # 1 A
printObject_4(1, obj=SomeObject('ABC'))  # 1 ABC
```

The problem with `printObject_3` is that you can change the default value inside the function:

```py
def printObject_3_buggy(idx, obj=SomeObject('A')):
    print(idx, obj.A)
    obj.A = 321

printObject_3_buggy.__defaults__  # (SomeObject(A='A'),)

printObject_3_buggy(1)  # 1 A

printObject_3_buggy.__defaults__  # (SomeObject(A=312),)

printObject_3_buggy(1)  # 1 321
```

The reason for that unexpected behavior is that the default value is mutable. Therefore, use the pattern in `printObject_4` when you want to use mutable default values or be careful and dont write to the keyword argument.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer! In my case, the printObject_4 solution will work just fine. Since you explained the impact on the default value with the printObject_4 solution: is there a way i could pass the object to the function like a pointer (speaking in C terms), such that it could be modified within the function?